# drupal how to customise drupal homepage with own html

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

I'm very new on Drupal 7, I've been trying to customize my home page by adding my own html on page.tpl.php, which works fine but my problem is that the what I add on the home page appears on all the other pages as well  and I don't want that. 
Can anyone tell me is the anther instead of page.tpl.php where I can put my html code so it show only on the home page or is there code I can insert so my html appears only on the home page?

please help, and please give a step by step solution as I'm a noob when it come to Drupal.

thank you in advance...........

Answer (score 5):

The Template file must be named as

```
page-front.tpl.php(Drupal 6)
page--front.tpl.php(Drupal 7)
```

This only affects the front page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template files

> page-front.tpl.php (Drupal 6)
>
> page--front.tpl.php ([Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.0))
>
> Put page-front.tpl.php (Drupal 6) OR page--front.tpl.php ([Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.0)) in your themes 
>   folder (/sites/all/themes/your_theme), and then clear the site chache here:
>
> http://yoursite.com/admin/config/development/performance ([Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.0))
>
> http://yoursite.com/admin/settings/performance (Drupal 6)

Your templates will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is variable available in page.tpl.php that return true if you are in front page : 
`$is_front`, you can check that before you add your htmls

Answer (score 0):

You can use panels to quickly customize the page. And you can specify any page as front page in Drupal. Go to Configure > site information and set the front page. 
Panels gives you flexibility in building the layout & adding content on it. Its the quickest way to build a custom page in Drupal